# How to print out all values inside of a ListNode array

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

Hello I am trying to print out all the values inside of a ListNode array, but can only seem to print out the values of the first index for each ListNode.

Here is the data contained inside the ListNode array.
ListNode[] lists = {[1,4,3],  [1,3,4],  [2,6]}

The output comes out as -> [1, 1, 2]

Expected -> [1, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 6]

Any help is appreciated.

```
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;

    public ListNode(){}

    public ListNode(int val){
        this.val = val;
    }

    public ListNode(int val, ListNode next){
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        //listnode array full of 3 indices of listnodes
        
        
        ListNode lists[] = {new ListNode(1, new ListNode(4, new ListNode(5))),
            new ListNode(1, new ListNode(3, new ListNode(4))),
            new ListNode(2, new ListNode(6))
        }; 
        

       for(ListNode ln : lists){
        System.out.print(ln.val + ", ");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print out the data in my LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296320/how-do-i-print-out-the-data-in-my-linkedlist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to have a recursive function that takes a Node and then if it has `next` then pass this `next` node to itself.

But otherwise, if you are sure that the array will only be 2D, then something like inner loop

```
for(ListNode ln : lists){
    System.out.print(ln.val + ", ");
    ListNode ln2 = ln.next;
    while (ln2 != null) {
        System.out.print(ln2.val + ", ");
        ln2 = ln2.next;
    }
}
```